# Why the performance is so different when slightly modify the number of iterations in GLSL for loop on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

First, I wrote down the code below. When running it on Nexus 6P, the performance got only 1 FPS.

```
vec4 show(vec2 start[100], vec2 end[100], int n, float scale) {
    vec4 color;
    vec2 loc = v_TexCoordinate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        loc = real_loc(start[i], end[i], scale, loc);
    }

    color = texture2D(u_TextureA, loc);
    return (1.0 - abs(scale)) * color;
}
```

After that, I tried to modify it as below. Then the performance got up to 60 FPS.

```
vec4 show(vec2 start[100], vec2 end[100], int n, float scale) {
    vec4 color;
    vec2 loc = v_TexCoordinate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        loc = real_loc(start[i], end[i], scale, loc);
    }
    loc = real_loc(start[3], end[3], scale, loc);

    color = texture2D(u_TextureA, loc);
    return (1.0 - abs(scale)) * color;
}
```

So my questions are:
1. Why is the performance so different?
2. How to write a high-performance code in GLSL? I cannot unroll all loops.
3. How to know the compiler actually do to my code?